# data directory not accessible android

Tags: android, root

I have rooted my device and I am trying to write file on /data/data folder, but
"Parent directory of file not writable: /data/data/test.txt" exception occur when
control going to create file.
Code:

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process process = runtime.exec("chmod 777 /data/data");
process.waitFor();
resultFile = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory()+ "/data/test.txt");
if (!resultFile.exists())
{
resultFile.createNewFile();
}
```

Please help me where I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Change your directory to /data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME/test.txt

Comment: I have also tried with /data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME/test.txt, but problem remain same.